# ASP.NET MVC Add View with ViewModels in another project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, view, viewmodel

Well in my solution I have view models in a different project from the original MVC web application. There is a problem however, that when I click the view folder to add view, it will no longer be able to find the view models from dropdown list. Below is a screenshot that demonstrates what exactly the problem is:

[image: View cannot find view models]

Sure I have an alternative solution that I can just create an empty view and then manually write @model ViewModelProject.ViewModel on the top. This isnt an ideal workaround though as I end up losing the benefits of scaffolding in ASP.NET MVC. Is there a way to make the view models show if they are in a different project/assembly? Anyone knows how to achieve this?

Comment: To be honest, I have never used Scaffolding in a real project. I always manually specify my view models. How hard it is to add the `model SomeClass` statement ?

Comment: From my experience, when you use *Add View* option in Visual Studio 2015, it takes a long time to load this window if you have a lot models. Even Visaul studio goes into *Not Responding* state for about a minute. So in my opinion adding empty views and manually writing `@model` is way to go. Of course it depends on usage of other options too.